# Google Material Charts: Forcing to show every label on horizontal axis

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Material Charts from Visualization API by Google in my project and I need to force showing every label on horizontal axis. Now there is approximately 30 columns and plenty of space next to each other, but it shows only 6 labels of them.

I've got in options set:

```
hAxis: { 
            minTextSpacing: 0,
            showTextEvery: 1,
            slantedText: true
        }
```

Which works properly in Classic Charts, but the same settings doesn't seem to work in Material Charts. Is it some kind of bug? And if so, is there maybe another way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's most likely not a bug. **Material Charts are still in beta** and some features aren't yet supported. The only option for using the missing features is to use Classic Charts (corechart).

I had problems with legend pagination, and found these resources:

https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1964

[Google Charts legend is not correctly displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460411/google-charts-legend-is-not-correctly-displayed)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/akJ-SOd5Zn0